# Auto Complete works for only the first character typed

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, telerik

I am using Telerik Raddropdownlist and have set the auto complete mode to suggest. When I type the first character in the text box, say '1', the dropdown suggests all projects starting with 1 which is fine( Lets say the first 2 projects listed after the match1 are 1234 and 1456). However, when I type lets say another '1', the textbox gets appended with "111234" which is basically both the 1s I typed along with the first element in the dropdown. Though the autocomplete mode is suggest and not suggestappend, I have no idea why the first match gets appended.

```
  this.radDropDownList1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            this.radDropDownList1.AutoSizeItems = true;
            this.radDropDownList1.DefaultItemsCountInDropDown = 20;
            this.radDropDownList1.DropDownHeight = 160;
            this.radDropDownList1.DropDownMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 200);
            this.radDropDownList1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F);
            this.radDropDownList1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(803, 23);
            this.radDropDownList1.MaxDropDownItems = 10;
            this.radDropDownList1.Name = "radDropDownList1"; 
            this.radDropDownList1.RootElement.AutoSize = false;
            this.radDropDownList1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(280, 36);
            this.radDropDownList1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.radDropDownList1.Text = "Select Project";
            this.radDropDownList1.DropDownListElement.AutoCompleteSuggest.DropDownList.Popup.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16);
            this.radDropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged += new Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventHandler(this.raddropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged);






  radDropDownList1.DataSource = ditems;
                radDropDownList1.DisplayMember = "ProjectName";
                radDropDownList1.ValueMember = "ProjectName";
                radDropDownList1.AutoCompleteDataSource = ditems;
                radDropDownList1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                Size popupSize = new Size(400, 300);
                radDropDownList1.DropDownListElement.AutoCompleteSuggest.DropDownList.DropDownMinSize = popupSize;
                radDropDownList1.DropDownListElement.DropDownMinSize = popupSize;
                radDropDownList1.ListElement.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",16);
                radDropDownList1.DropDownListElement.AutoCompleteSuggest.DropDownList.Popup.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16);



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utils.LogManager.write("Exception occur While populating Projects. error detail: " + ex.Message + "\r\nStacktrace: " + ex.StackTrace, "error");
                ExceptionDialog.ShowExceptionDialog(ex);
            }

            radDropDownList1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            radDropDownList1.Text = "Select Project";




 private void raddropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (radDropDownList1.SelectedIndex >=0)
            {
                cbTaskList.Select();
                PopulateTasks();

                if (this.GetMainForm().IsResetApp)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

I know theres a lot of redundancy in my code but I had a tough time resizing my AutoSuggest popup and I'm also new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 radDropDownList1.DropDownListElement.AutoCompleteSuggest.DropDownList.Popup.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 16);
```

was causing it to behave weird. It worked fine once I commented it out.